# how does cobj work in typo3 extension?

Tags: typo3

I am reading one typo3 extension file:

class.tx_jcjob_pi1.php

```
...
$this->template = $this->cObj->fileResource($this->conf['templateFile']);
...
```

class.tslib_pibase.php

```
...
var $cObj;
...
```

class.tslib_content.php

```
...
function fileResource
...
```

Question:
How  does this line work:`$this->cObj->fileResource($this->conf['templateFile']);`?

1. there is not such codes: such as `$cObj = new tslib_cObj()`, how did `$cObj` get instantiated?
2. there is no such codes like `require_once('class.tslib_content.php');` how could `$this->cObj` use the method in `class.tslib_content.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all done by Typo3's page renderer before your plugin's code is executed.

Because the class of your plugin `extends pi_base`, and pi_base was instantiated by Typo3, alot of functions are already there to leverage.

So if you would not have extended pi_base, `$this->cObj` would not be there, and you would need to create it yourself with for example:

```
$cObj = t3lib_div::makeInstance('tslib_cObj');
```